# How to use 'required' and 'optional' states with form api when using a select field?

Tags: forms, 10

I'm trying to create a form in Drupal 10 that will show an field that is both visible and required depending on the selection of a radio input that comes before it. The visible state seems to work well but for some reason the required and/or optional states do not seem to work on select fields.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['field_1'] = [
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => $this->t('Field 1'),
    '#options' => [
        'one' => $this->t('One'),
        'two' => $this->t('Two')
      ],
      '#required' => TRUE,
  ];

  // The field will become invisible but is still required.
  $form['field_2'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('Field 2'),
      '#options' => [
        'A' => $this->t('A'),
        'B' => $this->t('B'),
        'C' => $this->t('C'),
        'D' => $this->t('D'),
      ],
      '#required' => true,
      '#states' => [
        'visible' => [
          ':input[name="field_1"]' => ['value' => 'two']
        ],
        'optional' => [
          ':input[name="field_1"]' => ['value' => 'one']
        ],
      ],
    ];

  $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

  return $form;
}
```

When inspecting the HTML you can see that the code for the select is invisible but the required attribute is still present so when you hit submit the form will throw an error. This only happens for select field types as changing the type to textfield/radios seems to work without issues.

Comment: Unless something changed recently, `#required` is still server-side validation, and `#states` are client-side - they don't mix. The usual approach for your requirement is to add `#ajax` to the first select, and change the `#required` status of the second select in the builder based on the changed form state

Answer (score 0):

You have to tweak code like this:

```
  $form['field_2'] = [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => $this->t('Field 2'),
        '#options' => [
          'A' => $this->t('A'),
          'B' => $this->t('B'),
          'C' => $this->t('C'),
          'D' => $this->t('D'),
        ],
        '#states' => [
          'visible' => [
            ':input[name="field_1"]' => ['value' => 'two']
          ],
          'required' => [
            ':input[name="field_1"]' => ['value' => 'two']
          ],
        ],
  ];
```

I passed the required attribute inside state properly & removed the required attribute from the field definition

Note: Basically if you want to attach the required attribute to field w.r.t to Form state then you should attach with state property, if attach outside the state property then it 'll always bind to form element & 'll always fire

[Additional Info](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/form-api/conditional-form-fields#s-the-form-api-states-property):
Since states are driven by JavaScript only, it is important to understand that all states are applied on presentation only, none of the states force any server-side logic, and that they will not be applied for site visitors without JavaScript support

Comment: Does this still make the field required when javascript is disabled?

Comment: Strange, this does seem to work however the label is missing the (*Required) <span> that gets added to the label so I assumed it wasn't working before.

Comment: That's because it's only "required" on the front-end, not the back-end (the back-end being the one that produces the markup). If you use this approach be aware that users who disable javascript will still be able to submit the form, this is more "pre-validation" than actual validation of the data

Comment: i will still have the validateForm() hook setup to catch this. Disabling JavaScript seems to break all '#states' functionality.

Comment: Agree with clive , on disabling javascript  validation as well whole form state api not work  &  ans provided w.r.t to form state API context.